# How to get dedicated tag for git project?

Tags: git

To get the latest tag, I can do that by **"git describe"**

But when I reset to a tag, how can I get the tag before this dedicated tag?
Even both of them are pointed to the same commit object.

**For example:**

```
efeb8f3 (HEAD, master) Add d.txt

fad2363 (tag: 11.7.0.31) Add c.txt

240dbef (tag: 11.7.0.30, tag: 11.7.0.29) Add b.txt

f8c0b6a (tag: 11.7.0.28, tag: 11.7.0.27) Add a.txt
```

1. git reset --hard 11.7.0.30
2. how can I get the tag **"11.7.0.29"**?

or

1. git reset --hard 11.7.0.29
2. how can I get the tag **"11.7.0.28"**?

Any ideas?

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last tag of commit `treeish` using

```
git describe --abbrev=0 treeish
```

So if you want to get the last tag of HEAD, you can do this (HEAD is implied if no treeish is specified):

```
git describe --abbrev=0
```

And if you want to get the tree *before* some commit, you can just get the tag its parent is on, using `treeish^`:

```
$ git describe --abbrev=0 11.7.0.30^
11.7.0.29
```

You don’t even need to reset your working directory or the current branch for that.

---

`git describe` will only give you the single most-recent tag for the commit, so if you have multiple tags pointing to the same commit, you won’t be able to get the tags using `git describe`. You could use `git log` to get all the names though:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%d" -1 11.7.0.30
 (tag: 11.7.0.30, tag: 11.7.0.29)
```

Comment: Hey Poke, after I runned "git describe --abbrev=0 11.7.0.30^"
it returned 11.7.0.28

Comment: git reset --hard 11.7.0.30;
git tag -d 11.7.0.30;
git describe --abbrev=0;
Any other solutions?

Comment: But it's not worked when I reset to 11.7.0.29. It would get 11.7.0.30

Comment: I run a loop to delete those tags by git describe, but it seems so troublesome